# Don'tDestroyOnLoad not working between Scenes Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Scene 1 (GameUI), and Scene 2 GamePlay. I have a gameManager that holds gameobjects in the scene 2 GamePlay, and I have made it Don'tDestroyOnLoad(). This works as expected when loading scene 2 (GamePlay) from scene 1. However, when loading scene 1 (GameUI) from Scene 2 (GamePlay), gameManager (DontdestroyOnLoad) loses some of my gameobjects ?
How  can I fix this issue ?

Comment: thanks, that one is similar to mine, but it doesn't provide a proper solution to my question.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Check this out https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html